# Understanding How to Parse SQL Solution

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on the HackerRank **[Top Earners](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/earnings-of-employees/problem?isFullScreen=true)** problem. The problem states the following:

> We define an employee's total earnings to be their monthly salary x months worked,
> and the maximum total earnings to be the maximum total earnings for
> any employee in the Employee table. Write a query to find the maximum
> total earnings for all employees as well as the total number of
> employees who have maximum total earnings. Then print these values as 2
> space-separated integers.

The Employee table containing employee data for a company is described as follows:

| Column | Type |
| --- | --- |
| employee_id | Integer |
| name | String |
| months | Integer |
| salary | Integer |

The MS Server solution I found that works is:

```
SELECT
  MAX(months * salary),
  COUNT(salary*months)
FROM employee
WHERE salary * months IN (
    SELECT MAX(salary * months)
    FROM employee
);
```

What I am struggling to understand is how to break this solution down piece by piece. I know what is going on from **SELECT** to **FROM employee**, but after that I feel completely lost as to what this query is doing.

Comment: `COUNT(salary*months)` might as well be `COUNT(*)`. Alternative possible solutions include `SELECT TOP (1) months * salary maxSalary, COUNT(*) count FROM employees GROUP BY months, salary ORDER BY maxSalary DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a two part query:

Part 1:

```
SELECT MAX(salary * months) FROM employee
```

this gets you the max of salary * month. Pretty much that's as expected, but now that you know the max you can use it to go back and get the rest of the what you wanted by using it as your criteria.

Let's call all of the above `X`

Part 2:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(salary * months)
    COUNT(salary * months) 
FROM employee 
WHERE 
    salary * months IN (X);
```

That makes sense right? So just substituting `X` with the subquery from part 1 is the complete picture on this query:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(salary * months)
    COUNT(salary * months) 
FROM employee 
WHERE 
    salary * months IN (SELECT MAX(salary * months) FROM employee);
```

So subqueries can be used to evaluate an expression that becomes part of the where clause in your main query.

Comment: That does make sense, but it also makes me wonder why MAX() is needed in the main query? X is going to be a single value, so why is it necessary to evaluate MAX(salary*months) again?

Comment: Even though we already know Max (the maximum salary earned) - we don't know if there is one person or more than one person at that level - perhaps two, or three, or more employees are all at the maximum salary. So the next half of the query also adds the count of employees at that salary level.

Answer (score 0):

select max(months * salary), count(months * salary)
from Employee
group by months * salary desc
limit 1;